# Groovy : Unable to resolve class

Tags: jenkins, groovy

When I run my Groovy script via the command-line or Jenkins, I am getting an "unable to resolve class" error.

I have the following 2 groovy files within the same folder in C:\Users\myuser\git\productname\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build

Foo.groovy

```
package com.mycompany.build

class Foo {

  Foo() {
  }

  public void runBar() {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.name = "my name";
    System.out.println(bar.name);
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.runBar()
  }
}
```

Bar.groovy

```
package com.mycompany.build

class Bar {
  String name;
}
```

I run Foo.groovy using the command-line.

I am located within the following directory when I run Groovy:

```
C:\Users\myuser\git\productname\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build
```

This is what I enter on the command-line (cmd):

```
C:/java/tools/groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovy -cp C:/Users/myuser/git/myproject/mycompany-build/src/main/groovy/com/mycompany/build Foo.groovy
```

I get the following where it is unable to find the class "Bar", but the Bar.groovy file is in the same directory as Foo.groovy, not to mention that I do specify the -cp as well.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\myuser\git\myproject\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build\Foo.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class Bar
 @ line 9, column 9.
       Bar bar = new Bar();
           ^

C:\Users\myuser\git\myproject\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build\Foo.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class Bar
 @ line 9, column 15.
       Bar bar = new Bar();
                 ^

2 errors
```

Can you please advise on how I can get this running from the command-line?

Once I am able to get this running, I plan to run this within a Jenkins job.  I started off attempting to run this within a Jenkins job, but got the same issue which led me to look at running it off the command-line first.

I did attempt this with forward-slashes and back-slashes, but with no difference in behaviour.

Comment: If you are creating class in src folder for shared libraries, don't include src in the package path, otherwise you will get the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem in classpath and package usage.

To get it work

**1.** if your class declared in a package `com.mycompany.build` then groovy/java will look for it in the folder `com/mycompany/build` relatve to classpath. so you need exclude package-folders from your classpath:

```
groovy -cp C:\Users\myuser\git\productname\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy Foo.groovy
```

**2.** you can remove package declaration in both classes. in this case groovy/java will look for classes without package-folder prefix in your classpath: `C:\Users\myuser\git\productname\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build` and your command should work.
And if your current folder is folder with groovy classes then command could be simpler:

```
groovy -cp . Foo.groovy
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), in classpath you can have only *.jar*, *.zip* and *.class* files. The class *Bar* cannot be resolced because it is a *.java* file, not a **compiled** Java class (*.class*).

The following works for me:

```
C:/java/tools/groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovyc Bar.groovy
C:/java/tools/groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovy Foo.groovy
my name
```

Also note that since *Bar.class* is in the same folder as *Foo.groovy*, you don't need to specify the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the classpath argument to the directory containing the classes i.e. the one with `productname` as opposed to `myproject`

```
C:/java/tools/groovy-2.4.11/bin/groovy -cp C:\Users\myuser\git\productname\mycompany-build\src\main\groovy\com\mycompany\build Foo.groovy
```